# Correct way to insert new LI-s into OL-s list from JS arr

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a few lists in HTML and an array of data in JS.

I want new `<li>`s to be created in each `<ol>` according to the first element of `<li>`.

```js
const types = [{
    name: "house",
    sq: 250,
    year: 2020
  },
  {
    name: "apartment",
    sq: 70,
    year: 2010
  },
];

/*search key*/
document.querySelectorAll('.specs').forEach(ol => {
  const name = ol.querySelector("#name").textContent;
  const search = name;

  /*object search*/
  const res = () => {
    let result = []
    for (const item of types) {
      if (item.name.includes(search)) {
        return item;
      }
    }
    return result
  }

  /* THIS SHOULD ADD NEW LIs */
  var x = document.createElement("LI");
  var t = document.createTextNode(`${res().sq}`);
  x.appendChild(t);
  document.getElementById("hhh").appendChild(x);

});
```

```html
<ol id="hhh" class="specs">
  <li id="name">apartment</li>
</ol>

<ol id="hhh" class="specs">
  <li id="name">house</li>
</ol>
```

What I have now is: that new `<li>`s are created in the first `<ol>` only.
The wrong result is shown here:

[image: the wrong result is shown here]

how can I fix it, to make each `<li>` element be created in the right place (`<ol>`)?

Comment: Note that IDs have to be unique! You using multiple IDs multiple times. Because of that, your element will always be included to the first element with the ID `hhh`

Comment: 1. do not use the same `id` multiple times 2. debug, debug, debug. The main problem here is that `document.getElementById("hhh")` does not magically return the correct <ol> but the first one it finds, however you can easily fix this by using `ol` instead, which already is the correct list

Comment: You can also replace your res function with `const res = () => types.find(type => type.name === search);`

Comment: @tacoshy @ChrisG Thank you, it worked with this:
```
 var x = document.createElement("LI");
  var t = document.createTextNode(`${res().sq}`);
  x.appendChild(t);
  ol.appendChild(x); <---
```

Comment: @ChrisG wow, you are magician. Thank you. Oh i have so mane things to learn . Thanks

Comment: It's still invalid HTML and you should unlearn this ASAP. Also note that if your string template contains nothing besides an inserted string variable, there's need to use a template in the first place. Here's how I'd implement this: https://jsfiddle.net/72jv40q3/ (not optimized yet, will look for the same <ol> over and over)

Comment: Thanks, I've been doing this a long time, you'll get there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that IDs have to be unique! You using multiple IDs multiple times. Because of that, your element will always be included in the first element with the ID `hhh`.

To solve this, you need to give both `ul` an unique ID. The easiest way would be to use as the ID the name key:

```js
const types = [{
    name: "house",
    sq: 250,
    year: 2020
  },
  {
    name: "apartment",
    sq: 70,
    year: 2010
  },
];

for (let i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
  let el = types[i].name;
  let sq = types[i].sq;
  let year = types[i].year;
  document.querySelector(`#${el}`).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${sq}</li>`);
  document.querySelector(`#${el}`).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${year}</li>`);
}
```

```html
<ol id="apartment" class="specs">
  <li>apartment</li>
</ol>

<ol id="house" class="specs">
  <li>house</li>
</ol>
```