# Auto filling of several HTML elemnts after dynamic adding of them according to JS Array

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Recently i learned how to autofill `<ol>` `<li>` according to JS array elemnts

Now i have a more complicated task and what i learned there does not work

It should be cards elements.

Each card has `<div>` with *textContent* inside it's main `<div>`. Also have JS Array. Lot of child elements such as another `<div> <ol> <img>` currently created automatically for the first card.
**Task is** to make it continue autofilling new card element, not stopping on the first one.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/tonybarracuda/pen/WNzOopg?editors=1011) sandbox of the task. As you can see, second field is empty now

I have tried to solve it with:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach(div => {
  const name = div.querySelector(".name").textContent;
  const search = name;
......code from Codepen goes here...
});
```

But no result, it only worked with simle [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73050697/correct-way-to-insert-new-li-s-into-ol-s-list-from-js-arr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code needed some 'big' changes to make it work for looping over the types:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="flex">
    </div>
  </body>   
</html>
```

```css
* {
      font-family: monospace;
    }

    .flex {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: start;
      margin-left: 5%;
      margin-right: 5%;
    }

    .specs:before {
      content: "something";
      font-weight: bold;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    li:nth-child(1) {
      margin-top: 4px;
    }

    .cities:before {
      content: "";
      font-weight: bold;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    a:link,
    a:visited,
    a:hover,
    a:active {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
    }

    .card {
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
      width: 250px;
      height: auto;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin: 5px 10px;
    }

    .title {
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .car-image {
      margin-top: 2px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      position: relative;
    }

    .car-image:hover {
      cursor: zoom-in;
    }

    img {
      width: 250px;
      object-fit: contain;
    }

    img:active {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;

      z-index: 55;
      transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
      transform: scale(1.8);
    }

    .label {
      font-size: 9px;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: red;
      padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
      right: 8px;
      top: 16px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .download {
      margin: 4px 3px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      border: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
      border-radius: 0px;
      background-color: white;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .download:hover,
    .readmore:hover {
      background-color: #e7f0dd;
    }

    /*card description lists*/

    .col {
      margin: -8px 0px 0px 0px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
    }

    .laptime li,
    .specs li {
      list-style-type: none;
      line-height: 1.3;
      font-size: 13px;
    }

    ol li:first-of-type {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 13px;
    }

    li h4 {
      line-height: 0;
      margin: -8px 0px 10px 0px;
    }

    .laptime,
    .specs {
      margin-left: -12%;
    }
```

```js
const types = [
      {
        name: "Flat 1",
        tag: "house",
        architector: "MrA",
        year: 1998,
        weight: 1270,
        style: "classic",
        img: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTGI6MVnc4PyHx6DxWho0LVVwLhgmarjarvTcJtststZiaMFrdTdXA7DlN12EX2Tyqaudc&usqp=CAU",
        cities: [
          { area: "NY", qty: "1.05.354" },
          { area: "TK", qty: "4.35.354" },
          { area: "OS", qty: "4.49.354" },
        ],
      },

      {
        name: "Apartment 2",
        tag: "apt",
        architector: "Mr X",
        year: 2021,
        weight: 1720,
        style: "modern",
        img: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ_vbKVKMvq6fL5ChtQPl35YiNzW7yUYiWBQU8z_cr4GCEMnxZ1BWcVLcvh3vFYOxcb6MA&usqp=CAU",
        cities: [
          { area: "LO", qty: "1.06.354" },
          { area: "BAR", qty: "5.35.354" },
        ],
      },
    ];

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    types.forEach((item) => {
      console.log(item);

      /*calculate Perfomance Points*/
      const performancePoints = `${
        Math.round((item.weight / item.year) * 100) / 100
      }`;
      item.pp = performancePoints;
      let container = document.querySelector("div.flex");
      console.log(container);
      var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      newDiv.setAttribute("class", "card");
      container.appendChild(newDiv);
      var elem = document.createElement("img");
      elem.setAttribute("src", `${item.img}`);
      elem.setAttribute("class", "car-image");
      newDiv.appendChild(elem);

      //add label on the pic
      var elemPL = document.createElement("p");
      elemPL.setAttribute("class", "label");
      var elemText1L = document.createTextNode(`${item.tag}`);
      elemPL.appendChild(elemText1L);
      newDiv.appendChild(elemPL);

      // add button
      var elemP = document.createElement("button");
      elemP.setAttribute("class", "download");
      var elemText1 = document.createTextNode(`smth will be here`);
      elemP.appendChild(elemText1);
      newDiv.appendChild(elemP);

      var columns = document.createElement("div");
      columns.setAttribute("class", "col");
      newDiv.appendChild(columns);

      //

      let ol1 = document.createElement("ol");
      ol1.setAttribute("class", "specs");
      ol1.innerHTML = `<li>${item.year}</li><li>${item.weight}</li><li>${item.architector}</li><li>${item.pp} PP</li>`;
      columns.appendChild(ol1);

      //
      let result = [];
      for (const a of item.cities) {
        result.push(`<li>${a.area}: ${a.qty}</li>`);
      }

      let ol2 = document.createElement("ol");
      ol2.setAttribute("class", "cities");
      ol2.innerHTML = result.join("");
      columns.appendChild(ol2);
    });
```

Check out this [codepen](https://codepen.io/nekcoj/pen/MWVoJGJ) to look at the changes

Comment: Hello, Joacim! You are a magician! Such a smooth solution you did